# Adding heights of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through list items that all have a different height and are absolutely positioned. I want each li to appear lower than the previous li on the Y axis.

I'm stuck on how to add up all the previous prev_height variables. The third li Y coordinates are the sum of the height of the first two li's.

```
 $("li").each(function(){
    the_height=$(this).height();
    prev_height = $(this).prev().height();

    $(this).css({"left" : prev_height * 1, "top" : prev_height});
    console.log('prev height: '+prev_height);
 });
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="origin_left" style="top:100px; left:100px;">
    <li>Bus Stop Serves as Social Meeting Point Made of Giant Letters</li>
    <li style="top:; left:;">The organization builds communities by bringing together artists and audiences from diverse backgrounds to engage in the creative process. In a series of streetscape design workshops, hosted by Creative Alliance and Southeast CDC, residents of Highlandtown expressed a desire for an interactive bus stop that made a statement for the Highlandtown Arts & Entertainment District.</li>
    <li style="top:; left:;"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li style="top:; left:;">In response, Creative Alliance teamed up with Spanish collaborative mmmm….as part of the initiative TRANSIT&mdash;Creative Placemaking with Europe in Baltimore. With the help of local sculptors, they created BUS.</li>
    <li style="top:; left:;"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" /></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a variable that you initialise outside the loop:

```
var y = 0;
$("li").each(function(){
  $(this).css({ left: y, top: y });
  y += $(this).height();
});
```

I'm not sure if you want to set the `left` style to the same as the `top` style though, but I left it there as it is in the original code.

Comment: `.outerHeight(true)` if you want margins.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it.

```
var y = 0;

$("li").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "top": y
    });
    y += $(this).outerHeight();
});
```

**[See Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/nocazohecuho/1)**

**[See Complete Code](http://jsbin.com/nocazohecuho/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

```
var ht = 0; // change if needed;
$('.origin_left>li').each(function(){
  var e = $(this);  
  e.css('top', ht); ht += e.outerHeight(true);
});
```